Как изменить дизайн окон X11?
Я хочу изменить дизайн, что бы он соответсвовал:
Окна были минималистичными: никакого 3д и скевоморфизма, если так можно сказать не про apple
Кнопка для закрытия окна была свепху справа, и была единственной кнопкой для управления
Название окна было бы по середине, сверху.
Иконка должна быть слева от названия окна, с отсутупом 25px.
Для фокуса окна нужно нажать на него.
Рамок у окна быть НЕ должно
Углы окон должны быть скруглены на 25-30 пикселей
Использую FreeBSD 13.2
Меня попросили уточнить. Стандартный дизайн окон X11 меня конкретно не устраивает.

В Photoshop я прикидывал дизайн и хочу что то подобное:


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Нижний край не скругляется обычно если нужна тонкая рамка.
Поставь декоратор окон. Для линуксов из простых с темами есть metacity и xfwm4.
Возьми за основу https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1238479 например и поправь радиусы и цвета.
Скругления снизу возможны только засчёт рамки. Если сделать её в цвет фона окна, то будет смотреться как безрамочное.
